# Asynchronous coding - waiting for all returns - performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I have code similar to the following pseudo code:

```
static int counter;

function GetCalculations()
{
     for (x service calls)
     {
          service.BeginCalc(MyCallback);

          Interlocked.Increment(counter);
     }

     while(counter > 0)
     {
         //Wait for all results to return
     }

     return;
}

static function MyCallback()
{
   try
   {
   ... process results
   }
   finally
   {
      Interlocked.Decrement(counter);
   }
}
```

My question is in relation to the wait in the above code (the while (counter > 0)).  Is this going to be a performance issue?  I know that the multiple calls that I am making (to remote web services) take at least a few seconds to return - would I be better introducing something like a Thread.Sleep() in the while loop so that I am only checking for all returned every quarter second or so?

My gut instinct is that putting thread sleeps into my code smells a bit, but I'm just not well enough versed in this kind of code to say one way or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use task parallel library. It has easy to use mechanisms to wait on Tasks

Below is an example from MSDN

```
    Task[] tasks = new Task[3] 
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MethodA()),
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MethodB()),
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MethodC())
    };

//Block until all tasks complete.
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Made for some interesting reading.  Will post an amend to my answer when I get a bit of time outlining how I've done this using async tasks.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the point of having the async calls would be if you're just going to block until they return.  Sounds like you've got GetCalculations() being called from another function that needs the results before it can proceed.  Instead of blocking the thread, what about moving the dependent code to its own function?  Then call that function in your callback.  If you need to make sure all the callbacks are finished, you can just check the counter in the callback function before you call the function that contains the dependent code.

Comment: The point of the async calls is to make my multiple service calls (up to five) run in parallel, rather than in sequence.  This reduces my wait time to be (approx) the single longest wait time, rather than the sum of the wait times.  I need all the results returned before I can then proceed with the next step.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on .NET 4 you could, as has been mentioned, use the TPL (Task Parallel Library).

Otherwise, you have [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) (Rx.NET), which is also built to compose asynchronous operations together

If you don't want to use any third party library at all, you could create a bunch of [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) instances, which you can then wait for using the [WaitAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.waitall.aspx) static method.